# How to get iOS private relay enabled/disabled status in swift

Tags: ios, swift, dns, vpn, icloud

How to check whether user has enabled private relay or not in my ios app?

There are many similar questions on StackOverflow with 0 answers.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no method that allows you to query the state of Private Relay locally.

If you have a backend you can try to see if the IP address of the client sending the request is one of the listed egress IP addresses.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).